# How do I run a service with numactl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, database, numa, mongodb

I need to do something like this to run MongoDB

```
$numactl --interleave=all /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf &
```

What should I change to be able to run the mongo daemon with the options above?

Answer (score 6):

It depends from how you are managing your services.

### With a daemontools-family service manager, just that.

Your current `run` program will in essence boil down to

```
#!/bin/nosh
chdir /
setuidgid mongodb
mongod
```

This is in fact the very basic MongoDB `run` program that comes in the regular services bundle of [my nosh suite](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/), which doesn't use a shell as a script interpreter.  shell-interpreted `run` scripts for daemontools-managed services like [the one used by contegix](http://repository.contegix.com/software/djb/daemontools/services/service.mongodb/run) or [Yoshiaki Kawazu's one](https://github.com/kawaz/daemontools-mongo/blob/master/run) may look more complex but all end up having an `exec setuidgid mongodb mongod` command *somewhere*, even if it is hidden behind shell variable expansions.

With daemontools-family service managers, `run` programs such as these are in essence simple sequences of chain-loading commands.  The `numactl` program is a chain-loading command too, that modifies settings of its own process then chains to a program named on its command line.  It fits right in with daemontools tools such as [`setuidgid`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/setuidgid.8.html).

So you just add `numactl` into the chain there, which would be

```
#!/bin/nosh
chdir /
numactl --interleave=all --
setuidgid mongodb
mongod
```

in a nosh script or

```
exec \
numactl --interleave=all -- \
setuidgid mongodb \
mongod
```

in a shell script.  (In a shell script, you can make the script try to auto-detect the presence of `numactl`.  Just nick the mechanism from the upstart folk, below.)

Then just restart the service with (nosh only)

```
system-control condrestart mongod.service
```

or with

```
svc -t /service/mongodb
```

if you are using the old conventional daemontools `/service` directory.

### With systemd, just that.

In your `mongod.service` unit file there will be a section that has

```
[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mongod $OPTIONS run
```

This is what you will find in [the systemd service unit that comes supplied with mongodb](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/mongod.service), which is slightly but not much more complex.

So you just do as you suggested and modify the `ExecStart` setting:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/numactl --interleave=all -- /usr/local/bin/mongod $OPTIONS run
```

Either put this in a replacement `/etc/systemd/service/mongod.service` unit file to completely override the package-supplied unit file, or retain the package-supplied unit file and use an override for just that setting in (say) `/etc/systemd/service/mongod.service.d/numactl.conf`.

Then just reload the service unit from file(s) with

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and restart the service with

```
systemctl condrestart mongod.service
```

### With upstart, nothing at all.

The answers at https://askubuntu.com/questions/293468/ over on AskUbuntu are approaching 2 years old, now.  In the meantime, [`numactl` capability has been placed](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/1beb3d92996d658e5612aec1b68fbcbe7e7ac4a9) into [the package-supplied upstart job file](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/mongod.upstart).

So your system, presuming that it is up to date, should already be doing this and you shouldn't even need a

```
initctl restart mongodb
```

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179798/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177395/5132

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted.  Can anyone give me more details on why it was done?

Comment: What do you put in numactl.conf?