# lsb - log_daemon_msg echoes messages in shell console!

Tags: logs, console, daemon, init, start-stop-daemon

```
#!/bin/sh
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
log_daemon_msg "this is a daemon s message"
```

On the shell console, it prints,

```
this is a daemon s message
```

A daemon process doesn't have stdout at all. So why do `daemon startup` scripts write to `stdout`? Are they not supposed to use `syslog` file? How can I redirect the init logs to a system log file so that I can debug boot time issues?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: My first guess is that syslog is handling these messages as important that they are printed to the console.

Comment: no, i don't see `/etc/init.d/ssh` log_daemon_msg stuff inside my `/var/log/syslog`. and `log_daemon_msg` source code also doesn't have the logic to write messages to a file.

Comment: From what I've read, the lsb init functions are used while stopping and starting services and print status messages like [ OK ], or [ Failed ]. See http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-generic/LSB-generic/iniscrptfunc.html for details

Answer (score 2):

> A daemon process doesn't have stdout at all.

Not true. If one's dæmons are being managed by one of the daemontools family of toolsets (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179798/5132), then the dæmon will have inherited an open standard output file descriptor, for a pipe that connects it to a logging service.  If one is using systemd, then (in the default configuration) the the dæmon will have inherited an open standard output file descriptor, for a socket that connects it to the systemd journal service.

In any case, you are conflating the `init.d` script, which *manages* the dæmon, with the dæmon itself.  With System V `rc` and with systemd, the `init.d` script merely causes the starting and stopping of the dæmon process proper.  (In the System V `rc` case it does this with helpers such as `start-stop-daemon`.  In the systemd case, it uses `systemctl` to send commands over D-Bus RPC to process #1.)  It isn't the dæmon process itself.

The standard output of the dæmon process isn't necessarily any relation at all to the standard output of the `init.d` script.  And it's the standard output of the latter that you are addressing with `log_daemon_msg`.  This shell function, and its relatives, print friendly messages *from the dæmon management script*, showing what the management script is doing as it attempts to enact dæmon control commands.  They aren't being used *in the dæmon itself*.

Ironically, since daemon management is done differently with systemd, all of the `log_daemon_msg` commands become irrelevant, since any management script that sources `/lib/lsb/init-functions` ends up diverting all control commands to `systemctl`.

> How can I redirect the init logs to a system log file so that I can debug boot time issues?

You have a task.  You've decided that a subtask of that task is somehow addressible with `log_daemon_msg`, and here you are asking how to get `log_daemon_msg` to do something that it wasn't designed to do.  Concentrate upon your *real* question.

Ubuntu 14.04 uses upstart.  That has an `/etc/init/rc.conf` upstart job that provides backwards compatibility with System V `rc` by actually running System V `rc` whenever a runlevel event occurs.  This job is [listed in *the upstart Cookbook*](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#the-rc-job) and as you can see uses [the `console output` stanza](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#console-output).

As you can see from the *Cookbook*, with upstart — as well — dæmons (by default) inherit an open standard output file descriptor that is connected to upstart's per-job logging mechanism.  Yet again, the notion that dæmons "don't have standard output" is wrong.  The `/etc/init/rc.conf` job uses the (non-default) option of connecting the standard output to the console.  This of course also redirects the output of the various dæmon management scripts that System V `rc` spawns, in its turn.

So if you want to log the output of your `/etc/init/rc.conf` job, and all of the System V management scripts that it spawns, elsewhere, modify that job specification.

If you want to debug boot-time issues, then employ the mechanisms [that are described in *the upstart Cookbook*](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#debugging) (and also on the AskUbuntu Stack Exchange in several answers) for boot-time debugging.

### Further reading

- [runlevel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/runlevel.7.html).  Ubuntu 14.04 manual pages.  Canonical.
- [startup](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/startup.7.html) Ubuntu 14.04 manual pages.  Canonical.
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/36200/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/116407/
- https://superuser.com/questions/403847/