# What are the daemon user and group for?

Tags: security, openbsd, daemon, privileges

I am configuring a web server on OpenBSD and I can see in `/var/www/` that all directories except `/var/www/cache/` are `root:daemon`.

I then see that the user for the `daemon` group is `daemon`

```
$ grep daemon /etc/group
daemon:*:1:daemon
$ grep daemon /etc/passwd
daemon:*:1:1:The devil himself:/root:/sbin/nologin
_tftp_proxy:*:108:108:tftp proxy daemon:/nonexistent:/sbin/nologin
_ftp_proxy:*:109:109:ftp proxy daemon:/nonexistent:/sbin/nologin
```

What is the purpose of the `daemon` user and the `daemon` group?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198713/117549

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are legacy thing ; daemon user & group are respectively unprivileged meant to be used by multiple applications to get restricted access to the system.

Now days you should use a dedicated user & group where they will get a special namespace of User type for security matter.