# Custom daemon: which user could I use to run as, to avoid using root?

Tags: daemon, non-root-user

I want to write a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) that launches after boot, before login, that does background communication over [USB-rawhid](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi) with an [Arduino microcontroller](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Arduino_Pro_Micro).

I would like to run this daemon as non-root.

I would also like to avoid creating a new user, just for this daemon.

Are there any system-generic users that could be (re)used for this?

I see in my `/etc/shadow` a user listed, named `daemon` but...

```
# su daemon
This account is currently not available.
```

I am currently targeting:

- [Ubuntu 21.04](https://releases.ubuntu.com/21.04/)
- [`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)
- native code, in C, compiled for amd64

It would be a bonus if this generic user would be available in default Debian and Ubuntu installs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Bib, the error message you receive when trying to switch to the `daemon` user is because the login shell of that user is set to `/sbin/nologin`. This is so that no-one can work as this user on the console, which is reasonable in order to avoid unwanted interference with services operated as that user. It does not mean that `systemd` is unable to run a program using that user's UID, so you can use the `daemon` user the way you intended.

Please note however that while it appears that the `daemon` user and group were originally [introduced exactly for that purpose](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/619501/377345), it is nowadays actually the recommended approach to create dedicated "low-privileged" users for custom services you want to set up on your computer.

Since you explicitly stated that you want to run the service using `systemd`, you can use the `User=` directive to specify the user as which the binary is to be run. Just add

```
User=daemon
```

to the `[Service]` section of your `.service` file. See [the `systemd` documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=) for more info.